# Creating homes using nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

First this is all of my code

```
  #models/user.rb
  class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trips
  has_many :homes, through: :trips
  has_secure_password
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trips
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :homes
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, presence: true
  validates :password, confirmation: { case_sensitive: true }
end
```

```
#home.rb
class Home < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trips
  has_many :users, through: :trips
  validates :address, presence: true
end
```

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @home = Home.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def new

    if params[:user_id]
      @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
      @home = @user.homes.build
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
    binding.pry
    @home = Home.new
  end

  private
  def home_params
    params.require(:home).permit(:address, :user_id)
  end
end
```

I am trying to do something like this so that the home created is associated with the user that is creating it.

```
  def create
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
    @home = Home.new(home_params)
    if @home.save
      @user.homes << @home
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

The problem is that the :user_id is not being passed into the params. So the @user comes out as nil. I can't find the reason why. Does this example make sense? Am I trying to set the associations correctly? Help or any insight would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into using an authorization system like devise, which stores the user id in an encrypted session cookie. You should not be accepting the user id from the parameters here as it makes it trivial for a malicious user to pass any id and thus create resources as another user or edit other users resources.

Comment: I have a current_user method defined in the application_controller.rb in my controllers directory. I don't know how to access that within my homes_controller. I have tried many things. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you would typically create resources as the current user is with an authentication such as Devise - not by nesting the resource. Instead you get the current user in the controller through the authentication system and build the resource off it:

```
resources :homes
```

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController

  ...

  # GET /homes/new
  def new
    @home = current_user.homes.new
  end

  # POST /homes
  def create
    @home = current_user.homes.new(home_parameters)
    if @home.save
      redirect_to @home
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

This sets the `user_id` on the model (the Trip join model in this case) from the session or something like an access token when dealing with API's.

The reason you don't want to nest the resource when you're creating them as a specific user is that its trivial to pass another users id to create resources as another user. A session cookie is encrypted and thus much harder to tamper with and the same goes for authentication tokens.

by using `if params[:user_id]` and `User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])` you are really just giving yourself potential nil errors and shooting yourself in the foot. If an action requires a user to be logged use a `before_action` callback to ensure they are authenticated and raise an error and bail (redirect the user to the sign in). Thats how authentication gems like Devise, Knock and Sorcery handle it.